# Draw and study the discontinuous of $g(x)=\lfloor \sin(x) \rfloor$

Tags: real-analysis, contest-math

> Draw and study the discontinuous of $g(x)=\lfloor \sin(x) \rfloor$

$$g(x)=\begin{cases} -1 & x\in (-\pi,0) \\
 0 & x \in [0,\pi]\setminus \lbrace \frac{\pi}{2} \rbrace \\
1 & x=\frac{\pi}{2}
 \end{cases}.$$

I draw it like this:

[image]

We have that

$\lim_{x \to 0^-} g(x)=-1$ and $\lim _{x \to 0^+} g(x)=0$.

$\lim _{x \to {-\pi}^-} g(x)=0$ and $\lim _{x \to {-\pi}^+} g(x)=-1$

$\lim _{x \to {+\pi}^-} g(x)=0$ and $\lim _{x \to {+\pi}^+} g(x)=-1$

$\lim _{x \to {\frac{\pi}{2}}} g(x)=0$ but $f(\frac{\pi}{2})=1$

$\lim _{x \to {\frac{-3\pi}{2}}} g(x)=0$ but $f(\frac{-3\pi}{2})=1$

So, I think

The limit doesn’t exist if $\sin(x)=1$ or $\sin(x)=0$, this means that if $x=n \pi$ where $n\in \Bbb{Z}$, or if $x=2k \pi + \frac{\pi}{2}$ where $k \in \Bbb{Z}$

Therefore, the discontinuity points are $\lbrace k\pi, 2k \pi + \frac{\pi}{2} \mid k \in \Bbb{Z}\rbrace$.

Is that true, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is true that those are the discontinuities, you can use that $\sin(x)$ is a periodic function with period $2\pi$ to formalize your intuition.